# How to measure the interval $(1, 3]$ with specific measure $\mu$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(0, 1]$ with definition:
$$
\mu\left((k2^{-n} - 2^{-m}, k2^{-n}]\right) = 3^{-n} + 3^{-m}
$$
where $k$ is odd and $m, n \in N$ and $m \geq n$.
Calculate $\mu((0, \frac{1}{3}])$.
Hint: $\frac{1}{3} = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^j}$
I've tried coming up with a sequence od disjoint intervals that the union comes to $(0, \frac{1}{3}$ but i can't come up with a way to measurue the singelton $\{\frac{1}{3}\}$

Comment: Do you mean the measure of the interval is $3^{-n}-3^{-m}$?

Comment: No, sorry, it's +

Answer (score 1):

Taking $k=1$ and $n=m$, we see that $\mu\big((0,2^{-n}]\big)=2\cdot3^{-n}$. This holds for any $n$, in particular for $n=2$, which gives us that $\mu\big((0,\tfrac{1}{4}]\big)=\tfrac{2}{9}$.

Based on the hint, can we get the measure of $(\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{1}{4}+\tfrac{1}{16}]$? Indeed we can. Note that $\tfrac{1}{4}+\tfrac{1}{16}=\tfrac{5}{16}$, which suggests taking $k=5$ and $n=m=4$. Then $\tfrac{1}{4}+\tfrac{1}{16}=5\cdot 2^{-4}$ and $\frac{1}{4}=5\cdot 2^{-4}-2^{-4}$. This means that $\mu\big( (\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{1}{4}+\tfrac{1}{16}]\big)=\tfrac{2}{3^4}$.

To move forward, let $S_r:=\sum_{k=1}^r \tfrac{1}{4^k}$. It is easy to see that $S_r=\tfrac{4^r-1}{3}\cdot\tfrac{1}{4^r}$. Crucially, note that $\tfrac{4^r-1}{3}=1+4+4^2+\dots +4^{r-1}$ is always odd (for $r\geq 1$). Let us also denote $I_r:=(S_r,S_{r+1}]$ and note that we've computed $\mu(I_0)$ and $\mu(I_1)$ so far.

What about $I_r$ in general. Let $k:=\tfrac{4^{r+1}-1}{3}$ and $n=m=2(r+1)$. Then $k2^{-n}=S_{r+1}$ and $k2^{-n}-2^{-m}=S_r$. So $\mu(I_r)=2\cdot3^{-2(r+1)}$.

Let us set $J_r:=\cup_{k=1}^r I_r$. It is trivial to see that the union is disjoint and that $J_r=(0,S_{r+1}]$. This means that $\mu(J_r)=2\sum_{k=1}^{r+1}\tfrac{1}{9^k}$. Moreover, as the hint suggests, $S_r\to \tfrac{1}{3}$ as $r\to \infty$ and since $J_r\subset J_{r+1}$ we can use the continuity from below of $\mu$ to conclude that $\mu\big((0,\tfrac{1}{3}]\big)=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty 9^{-k}=\tfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually came up to the last two lines of your solution. My question is, how could we prove that $\mu$ is continuous from below. I know that since it is a measure it should follow straight from the definition but I was uneble to prove it.

Comment: @VlakecTomaz Ah, ok. This is one of the first properties you prove for a measure. You should be able to find this in any textbook or any measure theory course notes as one of the first 2-3 lemmas proved after defining a measure. The idea is that your measure, by definition, satisfies $\mu(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)$ whenever the sets $A_n$ are disjoint. Lower continuity is an immediate consequence of this after you use something called 'disjointification', i.e., after you construct disjoint sets $B_n$ such that $\cup B_n=\cup A_n$.

Comment: @VlakecTomaz if you cannot find it in some textbook or lecture notes or the hint above is not sufficient, let me know and I can add a short reply with the proof.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not necessary, my problem was mostly that it is stated in the problem that $\mu$ is a measure, and I suppose that I can take it at face value and use continuity from bellow, but I got stuck trying to prove that $\mu$ in this specific case is an actual measure, does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But I would still suggest you look it up. It's a simple and neat proof.